# two fragments in the same Activity

Tags: android, fragment

My fragment extends BaseFragment which has CMYJsonHttpResponseHandler in it. and if the handler returns error num -622. the basefragment will launch a dialog.
and my two fragments in the same Activity. so the dialog will create twice. but i want to crate once in the activity. activity code is like this:

```
CMYGoodsListFragment commodityFragment = new CMYGoodsListFragment(this);
        Bundle commodityBundle = new Bundle();
        commodityBundle.putString(KEY_INTENT_ID, "1");
        commodityFragment.setArguments(commodityBundle);
        fragments.add(commodityFragment);

        CMYGoodsListFragment serviceFragment = new CMYGoodsListFragment(this);
        Bundle serviceBundle = new Bundle();
        serviceBundle.putString(KEY_INTENT_ID, "2");
        serviceFragment.setArguments(serviceBundle);
        fragments.add(serviceFragment);
```

Comment: please share your code from where called the dialog?

Comment: How to judge the dialog is already exists

Comment: we have the method   alert.isShowing();

Answer (score 0):

use shared preferences to remember if the dialog is displayed.

Comment: other activities will also crate the dialog. if remember the dialog. it will only crate once in the app. do i think right?

Comment: you can attach a tag from where the dialog is shown and you can reset the preference when the dialog is dismiss in this way every time the dialog will be shown

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code.

```
private Dialog dialog = null;

    private void showDialog()
    {
            if(dialog!=null && dialog.isShowing())
                 return;
             /** Here create dialog */
    }
```